# Openlitespeed log format for GoAccess

Tags: logging, openlitespeed, goaccess

Im trying since hours to find an working Openlitespeed Log config to run with GoAccess. Also did not found any topic regarding openlitespeed logging with goaccess.

Example: Common Log Format (CLF)
"%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b"

Common Log Format with Virtual Host
"%v %h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b"

NCSA extended/combined log format
"%h %l %u %t "%r" %>s %b "%{Referer}i" "%{User-agent}i"

Tried all.

[Log Format Configuration GoAccess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vR2JI.png)

[ERROR GoAccess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVnb3.png)

[OpenLiteSpeed Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcif4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to share this setting with you which works in my case.

**OpenLiteSpeed access log format:**

```
%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b
```

**Access log output example:**

```
1.2.3.4 - - [21/Mar/2022:06:03:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 9555
```

**goaccess command:**

```
goaccess /usr/local/lsws/logs/example.com.access_log -o /var/www/example.com/report.html --log-format='%h %^[%d:%t %^] "%r" %s "%R" "%u" %T %^' --date-format=%d/%b/%Y --time-format=%T  --real-time-html
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, worked for me. Do you got any idea why the log rotation will always be 10MB? I changed the log rotation actually to 1000MB and 30 days in the openlitespeed virtual host log settings, but that won't work.

Comment: It works on my test server, could you confirm if you made the change to the access log, not the error log?

Comment: Yes I made the change for the access log for the virtual host

Comment: Please submit the issue to bug@litespeedtech.com for further help, and append this post link, thanks.